# How do you run PartCover with spaces in the path?

Tags: .net, hudson, partcover

I have a msbuild file that I'm trying to run from Hudson CI.  It outputs like this

> "C:\Program Files\Gubka Bob\PartCover
>   .NET 2\PartCover.exe" --target
>   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
>   --target-args "/noisolation" "/testcontainer:C:\CI\Hudson\jobs\Video
>   Raffle\workspace\Source\VideoRaffleCaller\Source\VideoRaffleCaller.Test.Unit\bin\Debug\VideoRaffleCaller.Test.Unit.dll"
>   --include "[VideoRaffleCaller*]*" --output "Coverage\partcover.xml"

I get this error

> Invalid switch
>   "raffle\workspace\source\videorafflecaller\source\videorafflecall
>   er.test.unit\bin\debug\videorafflecaller.test.unit.dll".
>   For switch syntax, type "MSTest /help"

WTF?  Looks like PartCover doesn't handle spaces in the --target-args well.  Or am I missing some quotes somewhere?  Has anyone gotten something like to to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely right that you forgot to quote the path. Read the [guide on how to integrate PartCover with MSBuild](http://chiragkumar.blogspot.com/2008/10/partcover-integration-with-msbuild.html).

```
--target-args=
Argument specifies arguments for target process. If target argument 
contains spaces - quote . If you want specify quote (") in , then 
precede it by slash (\)
```

So try to change your testcontainer parameter to

"/testcontainer:\"C:\CI\Hudson\jobs\Video Raffle\workspace\Source\VideoRaffleCaller\Source\VideoRaffleCaller.Test.Unit\bin\Debug\VideoRaffleCaller.Test.Unit.dll\""

Comment: Nope No go unfortunately.  I get C:\CI\Hudson\jobs\Video Raffle\workspace\partcover.proj(26,158): error MSB4025:
 The project file could not be loaded. Name cannot begin with the '$' character
, hexadecimal value 0x24. Line 26, position 158.

Comment: As you see, it seemed to have worked. Check the internet for the Error thrown by MSBUILD (MSB4025) - Something with your Project configuration does not seem to be right. But MSBuild was executed. There are several different issues out on the internet for that error; Several for a misconfiguration of project files and at least one is a bug.

Comment: You were right but in MSBuild you need to use &quot; for a quote